# Magento website page redirects to localhost dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9

I transfer my Live site to localhost and changed the URL in core_config_data table.Setting the database connection in local.xml file

My website home page is running well in localhost but when I click any link on home page it redirects to localhost dashboard.

here is my .htaccess file code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: remove `var/cache` folder

Comment: @Fme Extensions I already did but not working

Comment: is anyone there please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these step first and check

1. Remove your var/cache folder.
2. Fulsh all cache from admin.
3. Reindex all from index management

To reindex via command line

1 – Go to ‘shell’ folder in your Magento installation:

```
cd shell
```

2 – Execute reindex using this command:

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

Comment: When I doing your step 1 and 2 are done but in 3 step it showing error.  An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite

Comment: hey @Ashish are you there??

Comment: @xr33dx, You need to reindex via command line. Pl check my updated answer

Comment: I am new on magento and I dont know how to do it by command line

Comment: @xr33dx its not magento. Just open your terminal and use cd command to change the directory and type your project root folder path  of your system starting with /

Comment: @xr33dx Its just time out error. Other way is, You can try 1 indexing at a time from admin. One by one do all reindex.

Comment: I try one by one but same problem is showing in magento dashboard. and when i triggered the last command php -f indexer.php reindexall then it show message  php is not recognized as internal or externall command

Comment: @xr33dx, need to add php.exe path. follow this : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt

Comment: When I changed in my .htaccess here is code #RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*).html$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>   then it show page not found in my local host

Comment: Do not change the HTACCESS file. Use default. You have to do : By set "C:\xampp\php" in your PATH Environment Variable. Then Restart CMD prompt.

Comment: I did by command but same error showing

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem in my server .htaccess file,I replaced my server .htaccess file to Magento default .htaccess file and it works.

Thanx to all who try to help me